# Multiplication cross two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I need to discount my rate in df1 for the next 30 years. I don't know if I even need df2, but I put there for explaining my problem.

```
  df1
        Rate
   0    2.5 
   1    4.5
   2    2.5
   3    4.8
   4    3.8
   5    3.4 

  df2    
          0 1 2 3 4 .....30
    Year  0 1 2 3 4 .....30
```

The results should look like:

```
  df3
                 0                         1                         .....30
   0    2.5  (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
   1    4.5  (1+4.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+4.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+4.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
   2    2.5  (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+2.5)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
   3    4.8  (1+4.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+4.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+4.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
   4    3.8  (1+3.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+3.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+3.8)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
   5    3.4  (1+3.4)^(-df2.iloc[0,0])    (1+3.4)^(-df2.iloc[0,1)     (1+3.4)^(-df2.iloc[0,29]
```

I tried my code:

```
 y=np.power(1+df1.loc['Rate].to_numpy(),-df2.iloc[0].to_numpy())
```

Is it possible to add 30 columns in df1 after Rate and perform the calculation listed in df3? Thank you.

Comment: Where is your solution?

Comment: Are you sure Pandas is the best choice for this? It sounds like NumPy might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With general values in `df2` you can use broadcasting:

```
pd.DataFrame((1+df1.Rate.to_numpy())[:, None]**-df2.to_numpy())
#     0         1         2         3         4 ...
#0  1.0  0.285714  0.081633  0.023324  0.006664
#1  1.0  0.181818  0.033058  0.006011  0.001093
#2  1.0  0.285714  0.081633  0.023324  0.006664
#3  1.0  0.172414  0.029727  0.005125  0.000884
#4  1.0  0.208333  0.043403  0.009042  0.001884
#5  1.0  0.227273  0.051653  0.011739  0.002668
```

Or you can recognize that with your specific values it is just like a [Vandermonde matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html) but with negative powers, so

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vander(1+df1.Rate, N=31, increasing=True))**-1
#     0         1         2         3         4 ...
#0  1.0  0.285714  0.081633  0.023324  0.006664
#1  1.0  0.181818  0.033058  0.006011  0.001093
#2  1.0  0.285714  0.081633  0.023324  0.006664
#3  1.0  0.172414  0.029727  0.005125  0.000884
#4  1.0  0.208333  0.043403  0.009042  0.001884
#5  1.0  0.227273  0.051653  0.011739  0.002668
```

---

For completeness, to join the results use `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame(np.vander(1+df1.Rate, N=31, increasing=True), index=df1.index)**-1], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.